# How do I gzip my html source

Tags: php, html, gzip, lighttpd, compression

I would like to gzip the html sources of my webpages, what's the best way to do it on a lighttpd/php5 server.

I have tried to do it by editing my `php.ini` file with:

```
zlib.output_compression = On
zlib.output_handler = On
```

but it seems to be a transparent compression only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to enable mod_compress on lighthttpd in addition to the changes you made in your php file.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-mod_compress-gzip-compression-tutorial.html

Edit:

I believe you're looking for an html minimizer then. If you check out the headers that google is sending back they look like this:

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date    Thu, 22 Oct 2009 18:28:47 GMT
Expires -1
Cache-Control   private, max-age=0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding    gzip
Server  gws
Content-Length  3519
X-XSS-Protection    0
```

The "Content-Encoding  gzip" is what you're looking for if you want to check for to see if your webserver is properly compressing your files.

Comment: I have done this now but It's doesn't compress the actual html source of my files. Have a look at google.com source, thats what I want to do.

Comment: When you view source, your html will not look like it's compressed. It is compressed over the transmission and decompressed when it arrives at your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I'll try to look around how I can minimize the html source with php.

Comment: Really, I wouldn't bother. They aren't worth it especially if you're compressing your html & javascript already. I would invest more time in getting pages to load faster using subdomains & structuring your page properly. Check http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Comment: I found this script that could probably do what I was looking for but it seems that the project isn't maintained anymore: 
http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/php-code-sweeper/